# Error in `pivot_longer()` argument when updating `tibble` versions

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr, tibble

### Context

We would like to manage data from `dat_1`, in wide format, to `dat_2`, in long format. In order to perform it, we thought to use `tidyr::pivot_longer()` with argument `names_pattern = '(.+)_(.+)'`. It allows us to gather data as shown in the boxes, from `input format` to `output format`.

## *Input* data

```r
> dat_1

   original_id timepoint msp3_mfi msp3_dil pf_aarp_mfi pf_aarp_dil
   <chr>       <chr>        <dbl>    <int>       <dbl>       <int>
 1 id_005      C_0           10.5      400       22.2          400
 2 id_005      D10            8.5      400       10.25         400
 3 id_005      D13           11        400       10.2          400
 4 id_005      D28            8        400        9.75         400
 5 id_005      D60            7        400        0.30         400
```

## R code used

```r
dat_2 <- dat_1 %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = msp3_mfi:pf_aarp_dil,
        names_to = c('antigen', 'antigen_dil'),
        names_pattern = '(.+)_(.+)',
        values_to = c('mfi', 'dil'))
```

## Desired *output* data

```
> dat_2 

   original_id timepoint antigen antigen_dil   mfi   dil
   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <int>
 1 id_005      C_0       msp3    mfi          10.5     NA
 2 id_005      C_0       msp3    dil         NA      400
 3 id_005      C_0       pf_aarp mfi         22.2     NA
 4 id_005      C_0       pf_aarp dil         NA      400
 5 id_005      D10       msp3    mfi          8.5     NA
 6 id_005      D10       msp3    dil         NA      400
 7 id_005      D10       pf_aarp mfi         10.25    NA
 8 id_005      D10       pf_aarp dil         NA      400
 9 id_005      D13       msp3    mfi         11       NA
10 id_005      D13       msp3    dil         NA      400
11 id_005      D13       pf_aarp mfi         10.2     NA
12 id_005      D13       pf_aarp dil         NA      400
13 id_005      D28       msp3    mfi          8       NA
14 id_005      D28       msp3    dil         NA      400
15 id_005      D28       pf_aarp mfi          9.75    NA
16 id_005      D28       pf_aarp dil         NA      400
17 id_005      D60       msp3    mfi          7       NA
18 id_005      D60       msp3    dil         NA      400
19 id_005      D60       pf_aarp mfi          0.30    NA
20 id_005      D60       pf_aarp dil         NA      400
```

### Error

However, when we update de R (version R 3.6.3) session from `tibble 2.1.3` to `tibble. 3.0.1` we obtain the following error.

```r
Error: Assigned data `values_to` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 4 rows.
x Assigned data has 2 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

### Question

Any idea why we obtain this error in `name_pattern` when we update the `tibble` package version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know *why* the change occurred, I would guess that, at heart, this error has to do with your `dat_2` tibble not being [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). It's repetitive to include the difference between "mfi" and "dil" both as its own column `antigen_dil` and as two separate columns `mfi` and `dil`.

Depending on what your data mean, two formats that work easily with `pivot_longer` are:

```
dat_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = msp3_mfi:pf_aarp_dil,
    names_to = c('antigen', '.value'),
    names_pattern = '(.+)_(.+)'
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   original_id timepoint antigen   mfi   dil
#>   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 id_005      C_0       msp3     10.5   400
#> 2 id_005      C_0       pf_aarp  22.2   400
#> 3 id_005      D10       msp3      8.5   400
#> 4 id_005      D10       pf_aarp  10.2   400
```

or

```
dat_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = msp3_mfi:pf_aarp_dil,
    names_to = c('antigen', 'antigen_dil'),
    names_pattern = '(.+)_(.+)'
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   original_id timepoint antigen antigen_dil value
#>   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 id_005      C_0       msp3    mfi          10.5
#> 2 id_005      C_0       msp3    dil         400  
#> 3 id_005      C_0       pf_aarp mfi          22.2
#> 4 id_005      C_0       pf_aarp dil         400  
#> 5 id_005      D10       msp3    mfi           8.5
#> 6 id_005      D10       msp3    dil         400  
#> 7 id_005      D10       pf_aarp mfi          10.2
#> 8 id_005      D10       pf_aarp dil         400
```

If you really need the tibble in the format you described, you can use:

```
dat_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = msp3_mfi:pf_aarp_dil,
    names_to = c('antigen', 'antigen_dil'),
    names_pattern = '(.+)_(.+)'
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    mfi = if_else(antigen_dil == "mfi", value, NA_real_),
    dil = if_else(antigen_dil == "dil", value, NA_real_)
  ) %>%
  select(-value)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#>   original_id timepoint antigen antigen_dil   mfi   dil
#>   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 id_005      C_0       msp3    mfi          10.5    NA
#> 2 id_005      C_0       msp3    dil          NA     400
#> 3 id_005      C_0       pf_aarp mfi          22.2    NA
#> 4 id_005      C_0       pf_aarp dil          NA     400
#> 5 id_005      D10       msp3    mfi           8.5    NA
#> 6 id_005      D10       msp3    dil          NA     400
#> 7 id_005      D10       pf_aarp mfi          10.2    NA
#> 8 id_005      D10       pf_aarp dil          NA     400
```

The above snippets use the following to create `dat_1`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_1 <- 
  tribble(
    ~original_id, ~timepoint, ~msp3_mfi, ~msp3_dil, ~pf_aarp_mfi, ~pf_aarp_dil,
    "id_005",      "C_0",           10.5,      400,       22.2,          400,
    "id_005",      "D10",            8.5,      400,       10.25,         400
  )

dat_1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   original_id timepoint msp3_mfi msp3_dil pf_aarp_mfi pf_aarp_dil
#>   <chr>       <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 id_005      C_0           10.5      400        22.2         400
#> 2 id_005      D10            8.5      400        10.2         400
```

Comment: The first option works fine and simplifies the code a lot. Thanks so much @rsyoung.